# SQL Server : how to split a string into multiple rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can you help me with this situation?

I have this string in a `DESCRIPTION` column (yes, that's the only column with the data for this case =/ ):

```
"P.A. - Solicitação [945159][945171][944007][944836][944946][945065][945068][945074][945149][945087][946032][946139][947042][945552][945980][946194] - Chamado  Tipo: SOLICITAÇÕES DE T.I. Sistema ou aplicação: SISTEMAS T.I. Sub-processo: REVOGAÇÃO DE ACESSOS DE TERCEIROS  Solicitante"
```

I need to put these numbers in separate rows, like:

```
Row 1 - 945159
Row 2 - 945171
Row 3 - 944007
Row 4 - 944836
Row 5 - 944946
```

I have no idea how to do it. Can anyone help me, please?

I need this information because I receive these separated numbers from another table, but this one (with the `Description` column) doesn't have this numbers line by line, so I can't JOIN it like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_with_description 
INNER JOIN second_table_with_numbers ON Description = single_number
```

Comment: What have you already researched?

Comment: Below should work nicely

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from(
SELECT  
    CASE WHEN 
    len(left( Ltrim(rtrim(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(max)'))), charindex(']', Ltrim(rtrim(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(max)'))))  ))>0
    THEN 
    left( Ltrim(rtrim(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(max)'))), charindex(']', Ltrim(rtrim(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(max)')))) -1)
    else null end  AS String  
 FROM 

  (SELECT    
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([string], '[', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
     FROM  #temp) AS A  
     CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a) )a
     where string is not null
```

Comment: Hello, thanks! but it returned a error. XML parsing: line 2, character 164, illegal name character

Comment: It worked now. Thank you!

i've put two more replaces to deal with "illegal name character" error.

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to

- Use **[a string splitter like this one](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)** to split on the `[`
- Replace the `]`
- Return only rows that contain only numeric values

Using that function, here is how it works.

```
declare @table table (descrip varchar(max))
insert into @table
values
('"P.A. - Solicitação [945159][945171][944007][944836][944946][945065][945068][945074][945149][945087][946032][946139][947042][945552][945980][946194] - Chamado  Tipo: SOLICITAÇÕES DE T.I. Sistema ou aplicação: SISTEMAS T.I. Sub-processo: REVOGAÇÃO DE ACESSOS DE TERCEIROS  Solicitante"
')

select
    replace(s.Item,']','')
from @table cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(descrip,'[') s
where replace(s.Item,']','') not like '%[^0-9]%'
```

Comment: it returned this mensage: 
Invalid object name 'dbo.DelimitedSplit8K'.

Comment: Yes, you need the function i posted in the link... and that's why i said *using that function* in my answer